# Catch TXT from one part of the page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Im attempting to catch text on part of the page, and have it 'mirrored' on different part of the page.[image]

I am using word press, and the top section is the 'header.php' and bottom section is body.. What would be the best way to have the text on bottom section display on top section? Any suggestions?

Comment: Give us the URL so we can help...

Comment: http://www.angelgaragedoors.com/wordpress/

Comment: Seems like you can create a shortcode in WP and use it in both places.

Comment: got it, you wouldn't happen to know this shortcode by any chance would you?

Comment: how does the text change? based on the parameter attached to the URL?